# Chrome packaged app: have to open inspector every time reload

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am debugging my Chrome Packaged App(not legacy app), every time I reload my app, the pop-up inspector(developer) window disappear, I have to right-click my app window and select "inspect element" again.
Is there a way to "pin" the inspector window or open it automatically when reloading app?

Comment: The most annoying thing about having to select "Inspect Element" to perform debugging is that my initialization breakpoints have already passed and I can't step through that code (only event-driven code). I'm resorting to console.log() - unbelievable! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your application window an 'id', it will remember the size, position, as well as whether dev tools was open when last launched.

i.e.:

```
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
  width: w,
  height: h,
  id: 'MyAppId'  // add this
}, onWindowCreate);
```

I find this makes application development a lot easier!

Comment: Amazing, it saves my 10% total time of debugging, everybody should know it, thank you.